# CSS3 equivalent of HTML5 shiv?

Tags: css, html5shiv

Does anybody know if there is a plugin like HTML5 shiv for CSS3 that allows CSS3 to be rewritten and render properly in browser versions before IE9?

Comment: While all the suggestions above are good, please keep in mind that as more javascript polyfills are thrown at older browsers (namely, IE 6 & 7) the browser's performance could suffer. Use the polyfills in moderation - or try to sell the idea of using progressive enhancement. The tenet of progressive enhancement is that all browsers do not need to provide the exact same look or experience. Small differences such as square corners that would be rounded on another browser don't provide an unusable experience, even if they don't have the same kind of flair to them. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/).

Did the job for me a while back.

Answer (score 3):

CSS3Pie is awesome (and +1 to both the answers that suggested it), but it only covers a small number of CSS properties.

If you need other CSS features to work, then you may want to look at some of the following as well:

- [CSS Sandpaper](https://github.com/zoltan-dulac/cssSandpaper)
- [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/)
- Any one of several scripts [listed here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills)

Answer (score 1):

[CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) is a good one.